# List Index out of range.. works on google colab but not on local machine?

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, indexing, range

I'm trying to recreate this project on my local machine. It's designed to run on Google Colab and I've recreated it there, and it works just fine. I want to try running it on my local machine now, so I installed all the required packages, anaconda, Juypter Notebook etc.

When I come to the part where I process the images:

```
# Loops through imagepaths to load images and labels into arrays
for path in imagepaths:
  img = cv2.imread(path) # Reads image and returns np.array
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Converts into the corret colorspace (GRAY)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 120)) # Reduce image size so training can be faster
  X.append(img)

  #Processing label in image path   
  category = path.split("/")[3]   
  label = int(category.split("_")[0][1])   
  y.append(label)
```

It throws the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code has not been changed, for the most part, and the dataset is the same. The only difference is I'm running locally vs google colab. I searched online and someone said do len(path) to verify that (in my case) it goes up to [3], which it does (its size 33).

Code has changed here:

I did not use this line, as I'm not using google colab:

```
from google.colab import files
```

The "files" is used in this part of code:

```
# We need to get all the paths for the images to later load them
imagepaths = []

# Go through all the files and subdirectories inside a folder and save path to images inside list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False): 
  for name in files:
    path = os.path.join(root, name)
    if path.endswith("png"): # We want only the images
      imagepaths.append(path)

print(len(imagepaths)) # If > 0, then a PNG image was loaded
```

On my local machine, I removed the `from google.colab...` line, and ran everything else normally. The keyword files is used in the code snippet above, however when running it I was thrown no errors. `**NOTE len(path) on Jupyter shows 33, len(path) on Google shows 16..?**`

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I don't think it came from removing that one line of code. If it did, what do you suggest I do to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in one of your splits (you forgot to tell us which one is the one giving you problem). What is the value of `path` on google colab and on your local machine?

Comment: Hi @SergioR, the issue is with the split on Jupyter. That's exactly where the error is pointing to. When doing len(path) on google I get 16, but on Jupyter I get 33..?

Comment: Cay you provide the output of `path` for google colab and your local machine? You can use `print(imagepaths[0])` for this.

Comment: @user_3pij, `print(imagepaths[0])` results in the following:  `./leapgestrecog/leapGestRecog/00/01_palm/frame_00_01_0001.png` and on my local machine, its '.\\00\\01_palm\\frame_00_01_0001.png'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local machine is running on `Windows` while the `colab` runs on `linux` and the path separators are different for both.
Now you need to replace

```
category = path.split("/")[3]
```

with

```
category = path.split("\\")[2]
```

And your code should work.

Comment: Thank you! This was it, I didnt realize. Cheers!